# How can I pass a parameter to a selector?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, parameters, nssearchfield

I have an NSSearchField:

```
[searchField setAction:@selector(doSearchWithQuery:)];
```

Here is my doSearchQuery:

```
-(void)doSearchWithQuery:(NSString*)query{
```

How can I pass the contents of my searchfield into doSearchWithQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you're describing. A selector doesn't *do* anything or accept any parameters — it's just the name of the message to send. You can only pass arguments when you actually *send* a message. However, controls always pass themselves as an argument to their actions, so what you need is a wrapper method along these lines:

```
- (void)doSearchFromSearchField:(NSSearchField *)sender {
    [self doSearchWithQuery:[sender stringValue]];
}
```

And set that as the action.