# Setting a button's target/action and passing a particular string to the action

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, selector

I create a `UIButton` and add a selector with an `NSString` argument, but it gives a syntax error.

```
NSString*title=@"abc";

[backViewButton addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(buttonClicked:WithString:title) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Without the code, no one can debug this but you.

Comment: -1 Dammit, Jim, I'm a programmer, not a psychic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a parameter to a selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372468/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-selector)

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass arguments when you use `@selector`.

```
@selector(buttonClicked:WithString:title)
//              This here is invalid^^
```

That operator can only be used on a method name; the selector you get from it is later used to call the method, at which point arguments can be passed.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess without seeing the error is you forgot to put a colon at the end of your selector.  Probably ought to be `@selector(buttonClicked:WithString:title:)`.  Unless, as Josh Caswell suggested, you are for some reason trying to create a selector with an argument... that would be pretty strange, and incorrect.

Comment: Woops, sorry, Josh.  I have to admit, I spelled your last name incorrectly on the first try too.  Must be a bad night.